# To remove part of the href link?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm scraping Google search results.Here's my code part.

```
def select_wholePage(driver):
    items = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="main"]/div')
    assert isinstance(items, object)
    return items


def get_result(item_in):
    try:
        title = item_in.find_element_by_xpath('.//div/div/a/h3/div').text
        print(title)
    except exceptions.NoSuchElementException:
        return
    try:
        link = item_in.find_element_by_xpath('.//div/div/a').get_attribute('href')
        print(link)
    except exceptions.NoSuchElementException:
        return
    result = (title, link)
    return result
```

Output
-> I can get the desired elements, but when I print the link, "https://www.google.com/url?q=" is attached as shown below.
"https://www.google.com/url?q="
[image]

How to remove it?

Answer (score 2):

You could strip off that string using `lstrip()`.

```
s = "https://www.google.com/url?q=<some_query>"
s = s.lstrip("https://www.google.com/url?q=")
print(s)
```

```
<some_query>
```

Comment: Oh, I forgot lstrip(). I will use it next time. Thank you.

Comment: @SYMoon Are you aware that `.lstrip` does remove characters? Try it for `s = "https://www.google.com/url?q=logging"` and check if result is compliant with your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

If `https://www.google.com/url?q=` is fixed and always present `.replace` method should suffice, i.e.:

```
encased = "https://www.google.com/url?q=https://www.example.com"
core = encased.replace("https://www.google.com/url?q=", "", 1)
print(core)
```

output

```
https://www.example.com
```

I provided third argument to `.replace` which limits it to at most 1 replacement, in case `https://www.google.com/url?q=` would appear further.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if it's the cleanest way but you could do something like this:

```
google_url_prefix = "https://www.google.com/url?q="
url_cut_id = len(google_url_prefix)
link = link[url_cut_id:]
```

Comment: Wow! There is so many way to strip unnecessary string. I learned from you. Thank you!!

Comment: I'm glad you learned something! Although this solution might be faster in some case, the solution with lstrip is more robust since it won't remove more than needed if the google prefix url changes...